# inserting an html error page into php code when using a form

Tags: php, html, forms, embed

I have a form that emails the details.  I have successfully managed to insert a "thank you" page when the user submits their information.

However, when an error when the user does not fill out the details correct the validation picks this up and brings up an unformatted error page.

Is anyone out there able to help me format this error page please? My website is built in html, but the form uses a php script.

Here is my HTML form code

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
<table width="450px">
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label class="standard" for="first_name">First Name *</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input  color="#000000" background="#FFFFFF" type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label class="standard" for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="text" color="#000000" background="#FFFFFF" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label class="standard" for="email">Email Address *</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="text" color="#000000" background="#FFFFFF" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label class="standard" for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="text" color="#000000" background="#FFFFFF" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label class="standard" for="comments">Comments *</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<textarea  name="comments" color="#000000" background="#FFFFFF" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "my@email.com";
$email_subject = "New email from FM Fortune";


function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors in order to continue.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
}

$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "FM Fortune query below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

This is where my Thank you html code goes.



<?php
}
?>
```

Thank you for your help guys!

Comment: This is the second posting of this code, are you just trying to get us to do all your work for you?

Comment: what are you doing here? trying to find the pilot for your plane?

Comment: nope...just new to php.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
    header("Location: myErrorPage.html");       
}
```